# Why is my ceph cluster value(964G) of raw used in global secion far higher than that(244G) of used in pools sectio

Tags: ceph, linux-disk-free

#### Why is my ceph cluster value(964G) of raw used in global section far higher than that(244G) of used in pools section

```cs
[en@ceph01 ~]$ sudo ceph df
GLOBAL:
SIZE        AVAIL       RAW USED     %RAW USED
6.00TiB     5.06TiB       964GiB         15.68
POOLS:
NAME                    ID     USED        %USED     MAX AVAIL     OBJECTS
.rgw.root               1      1.09KiB         0       1.56TiB           4
default.rgw.control     2           0B         0       1.56TiB           8
default.rgw.meta        3           0B         0       1.56TiB           0
default.rgw.log         4           0B         0       1.56TiB         207
cephfs_data             5       244GiB      9.22       2.34TiB     4829661
cephfs_meta             6       168MiB         0       2.34TiB        4160
[en@ceph01 ~]$ sudo ceph osd df
ID CLASS WEIGHT  REWEIGHT SIZE    USE    DATA   OMAP    META    AVAIL   %USE  VAR  PGS
0   hdd 2.00000  1.00000 2.00TiB 331GiB 326GiB 1.64GiB 3.38GiB 1.68TiB 16.17 1.03  77
1   hdd 2.00000  1.00000 2.00TiB 346GiB 341GiB 1.69GiB 3.51GiB 1.66TiB 16.90 1.08  78
2   hdd 2.00000  1.00000 2.00TiB 286GiB 282GiB 1.31GiB 2.96GiB 1.72TiB 13.97 0.89  69
TOTAL 6.00TiB 964GiB 949GiB 4.64GiB 9.86GiB 5.06TiB 15.68
MIN/MAX VAR: 0.89/1.08  STDDEV: 1.24
```

info about ceph cluster:

```cs
>pool 5 'cephfs_data' replicated size 2 min_size 2 crush_rule 0 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 32 pgp_num 32 last_change 33 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0 application cephfs..
>pool 6 'cephfs_meta' replicated size 2min_size 2 crush_rule 0 object_hash rjenkins pg_num 32 pgp_num 32 last_change 31 flags hashpspool stripe_width 0 application cephfs
> max_osd 3
```

Answer (score -1):

This is due to `bluestore_min_alloc_size_hdd` being most likely set at `64K`.

More info here: [ceph df (octopus) shows USED is 7 times higher than STORED in erasure coded pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185503/ceph-df-octopus-shows-used-is-7-times-higher-than-stored-in-erasure-coded-pool/68186461#68186461)